# I can generate debug signed apk, but cannot release apk

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

I am trying to load new version of my app to google play and when I am trying to build, its ok, when I am trying to build signed debug apk its also ok, but when I try the release, it crashes. It says

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

How can i create signed release apk again?

Comment: did you check logs?

Comment: I cannot find them

Comment: Sorry, a question just to understand. If you have your signed apk why don't you just publish that one?

Comment: Debugable signed apk cannot be published (google play says because of security reasons)

Comment: in android studio use adb to find it. Run the app in device while opening the log at the same time. When the error will occur the logcat will tell you the error. Also set the logcat to show only errors and not verbose info because it would be very messy to find the error then.

Comment: If you can't find the Gradle Build window in Android Studio (it should contain the build log), then in a terminal go to your project directory and run "gradlew clean assembleRelease" and post the output here. Without it we have no idea what error you're getting. Also include the version of the android gradle plugin you're using and if you're using react native or not.